# Azure eventhub library for python

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am using eventhub for ingesting a lot of events. I have multiple consumers which are running behing a scaling group reading these events from the eventhub which has multiple partitions. I was going through the Azure SDK in python and was confused as to what to use. There is eventhubconsumerclient, eventprocessorHost ....

I would like to use a library where my multiple consumer can connect using the consumer group, the partitions are assigned dynamically to each consumer and checkpointing is made in the storage account, just like how I used kafka.

Comment: I used the sample code and this is the error I am getting "An exception (KeyError('offset')) occurred during balancing and claiming ownership for eventhub"

Comment: this is the link I am refering to : https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/5.0.0b6/#consume-events-and-save-checkpoints-using-a-checkpoint-store

Comment: Do you consider using "event processor host" in python? which uses consumer group and can set checkpointing.

Comment: In the later versions of python sdk, I can see eventhubconsumerclient as being used. See the link in the comment. Also have a look at error. I am trying to run the same example program provided in the link

Comment: It's a pre-release version, not stable version. Not sure if it has some potential bugs.

Comment: so which one shall I use... Is there a stable version for the same?

Comment: We should keep using the stable one. But the stable one uses "event process host". The pre-release version is not recommended for production usage.

Comment: but if you prefer to use the pre-release version, I will take a try. Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: It is there in the link : https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/5.0.0b6/#consume-events-and-save-checkpoints-using-a-checkpoint-store

Comment: can you please try and let me know. I am using the exact same code with only config changes

Comment: yeah, I'll take a try and let you know the result. Just for set checkpoint and use consumer group, right?

Comment: yes $default is the consumer group and for checkpoint I used storage account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

For production usage, I suggest you should use the stable version of event hub sdk. You can use eph, sample code is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/eventhub_track1/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhubs/examples/eph.py).

---

I can use the [pre-release eventhub 5.0.0b6](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/5.0.0b6/#consume-events-and-save-checkpoints-using-a-checkpoint-store) to use consumer group as well as set checkpoint.

But the strange thing is that, in blob storage, I can see 2 folders created for the eventhub: **checkpoint** and **ownership** folder. Inside the folders, there're blob created for the partitions, but blob is empty. More stranger thing is that, even the blob is empty, every time I read from eventhub, it always read the latest data(means that it never reads the data has been read already in the same consumer group).

You need to install [azure-eventhub 5.0.0b6](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/5.0.0b6/#consume-events-and-save-checkpoints-using-a-checkpoint-store) and use `pip install --pre azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob` to install **azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob**. For blob storage, you should install the latest [version 12.1.0 of azure-storage-blob](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/).

I follow this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob/samples/event_processor_blob_storage_example.py). In this sample, it uses **event hub level** connection string(NOT **event hub namespace level** connection string). You need to create an **event hub level** connection string by nav to azure portal -> your eventhub namespace -> your event hub instance -> Shared access policies -> click "Add" -> then specify a policy name, and select permission. If you just want to receive data, you can only select the **Listen permission**. The screenshot as below:

[image]

After the policy created, you can copy the connection string as per screenshot below:

[image]

Then you can follow this code below:

```
import os
from azure.eventhub import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblob import BlobCheckpointStore

CONNECTION_STR = 'Endpoint=sb://ivanehubns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=saspolicy;SharedAccessKey=xxx;EntityPath=myeventhub'
STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'


def on_event(partition_context, event):
    # do something with event
    print(event)
    print('on event')
    partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #the "a22" is the blob container name
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, "a22")

    #the "$default" is the consumer group
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR, "$default", checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store)

    try:
        print('ok')
        client.receive(on_event)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        client.close()
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried this one as well and I am keep getting this error : An exception occurred during list_ownership for namespace 'xxxxxxxx' eventhub 'xxxxxxx' consumer group '$default'. Exception is KeyError('ownerid')

Comment: @Nipun, can you follow my steps, and try to use a new blob container?

Comment: and if the error still occurs, please post your code, and all the packages(including version) you're using. So I can debug it to find the cause:).

Comment: after going through some document I see that the partitionmanager needs to have the ownership of the partitions and I guess it is trying to get that from the storage blob which is empty

Comment: @Nipun, maybe. But not sure why the blobs are empty, but can work well. And since it's pre-release, maybe it will be fixed in a few days.

Comment: it creates a ownership folder having 2 partition 0 and 1 files but they are blank. I guess because of which it is not able to find the 'ownerid'. I deleted everything and retried and still the same issue

Comment: a very nice article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-event-processor-host

Comment: @Nipun, do you mind update your post with detailed steps and code, and some screenshot of the error?

Comment: Thank you Ivan for your support, since I would like to have a production ready code, I will not use the beta sdk of python

Comment: I will go with eventprocessorhost class

Comment: This is what I am using : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/eventhub_track1/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhubs/examples/eph.py

Comment: @Nipun, ok, it's better to use stable version:)

Comment: I am facing one more issue let me create a separate ticket on stackoverflow and add the link

Comment: @Nipun, yeah, please add the link here later.

Comment: Can you please help me with this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207767/how-to-provide-the-complete-path-of-the-container-in-azurestoragecheckpointlease

Comment: @Nipun, ok, I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

azure-eventhub v5 has been GAed in 2020 Jan, and the latest version is v5.2.0

It's available on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/

Please follow the [migration guide from v1 to v5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/migration_guide.md) to migrate your program.

For receiving with checkpoint, please follow the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/receive_batch_with_checkpoint.py):

```py
import os
import logging
from azure.eventhub import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblob import BlobCheckpointStore

CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["EVENT_HUB_CONN_STR"]
EVENTHUB_NAME = os.environ['EVENT_HUB_NAME']
STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_CONN_STR"]
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = "your-blob-container-name"  # Please make sure the blob container resource exists.

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def on_event_batch(partition_context, event_batch):
    log.info("Partition {}, Received count: {}".format(partition_context.partition_id, len(event_batch)))
    # put your code here
    partition_context.update_checkpoint()


def receive_batch():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$Default",
        eventhub_name=EVENTHUB_NAME,
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,
    )
    with client:
        client.receive_batch(
            on_event_batch=on_event_batch,
            max_batch_size=100,
            starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    receive_batch()
```

One more thing worth to note is that in V5, we use the metadata of blob to store checkpoint and ownership information instead of storing them as the content of a blob in v1. So it's expected that the content of a blob is empty when using the v5 sdk.

Comment: Do you mean `azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio`? `extensions.checkpointstoreblob` does not seem to be a thing.

Comment: `azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblob` is the sync version -- https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob/

while `azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblobaio` is the async version -- https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio/

Comment: Right, thanks. For anyone else asking this question: The async and the sync package are installed separately.

azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob

and

pip install azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio