# How to provide the complete path of the container in AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager class

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-sdk-python

I am using EPH ( EventProcessorHost) class of Azure python SDK to receive events from the eventhub. 
It actually uses `AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager` for checkpointing and partitioning in the storage account. But I cannot see where I can write the full path of the storage account. Like it directly create files inside the specified container in the storage account. I would like to give the full path inside the container. Where can I do that?

Comment: Hi, may I know why you need to provide a complete path of the blob(like https://yy3.blob.core.windows.net/test2/$Default/0, right)?

Comment: right now if I have 2 partition 2 files are created directly in the container `eph-leases`. Since I will have lot of consumers group and event hubs, I would like to create a folder like `eph-leases/eventhub-namespace/eventhub-name/consumer-group/

Comment: You mean you want each consumer have its own checkpoint, right?

Comment: No but each consumer group

Comment: I will have a lot of consumer group and eventhubs. Would like to use the same container for all of them

Comment: If you would like to use the same container, you can simply specify the same container, but specify different consumer group. But the folder structure should look like 'eph-leases/consumer-group', is it ok, or you persist using the structure like  `eph-leases/eventhub-namespace/eventhub-name/consumer-group/ `?

Comment: I am not seeing even the consumer group folder being created. I can live with the folder as consumer-group

Comment: ok, I see. Never mind, I'll try to work it out:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203733/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-nipun).

Comment: I tried your test changes and it worked. Let me use this for now. Also looked at the changes. Thank you, very helpful

Comment: It worked like a charm.... you can post this as answer and I will mark it

Comment: OK, and just got the feedback from support team: They reported this as issue to product team, and if any feedback, they will let me know that.

Comment: Great thanks. Can you also help me with this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279601/hoe-to-get-the-consumer-lag-in-eventhub

Comment: I'll take a look today. I was out of office recently and sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my research:

In `AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager`, there is a parameter `storage_blob_prefix`, which should be used to set blob prefix(means directory for the checkpoint blob). But actually it does not work.

After going through the source code of `azure_storage_checkpoint_manager.py`, I can see **storage_blob_prefix** is actually assigned to **consumer_group_directory**, but **consumer_group_directory** is never used to create the blob for checkpoint. Instead, it just creates the blob directly inside the container.

So the fix is that we can modify the `azure_storage_checkpoint_manager.py`, by using **lease_container_name** + **consumer_group_directory** to create the checkpoint blob. I modified it and uploaded it [github](https://github.com/imeya/test). It can work well to create a directory for the checkpoint blob as expected.